# Writing to HBase in a Spark job: a conundrum with existential types

Tags: scala, hadoop, hbase, apache-spark, existential-type

I am trying to write a Spark job that should put its output into HBase. AS far as I can tell, the right way to do this is to use the method `saveAsHadoopDataset` on `org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions` - this requires that my `RDD` is composed of pairs.

The method `saveAsHadoopDataset` requires a `JobConf`, and this is what I am trying to construct. According to [this link](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@spark.incubator.apache.org/msg01494.html), one thing I have to set on my `JobConf` is the output format (in fact it doens't work without), like

```
jobConfig.setOutputFormat(classOf[TableOutputFormat])
```

The problem is that apparently this does not compile, because `TableOutputFormat` is generic, even though it ignores its type parameter. So I have tried various combinations, such as

```
jobConfig.setOutputFormat(classOf[TableOutputFormat[Unit]])
jobConfig.setOutputFormat(classOf[TableOutputFormat[_]])
```

but in any case I get an error

```
required: Class[_ <: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputFormat[_, _]]
```

Now, as far I can tell, `Class[_ <: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputFormat[_, _]]` translates to `Class[T] forSome { type T <: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputFormat[_, _] }`. Here is where I think I have a problem, because:

- `Class` is invariant
- `TableOutputFormat[T] <: OutputFormat[T, Mutation]`, but
- I am not sure how existential types interact with subtyping in the requirement `T <: OutputFormat[_, _]`

Is there a way to obtain a subtype of `OutputFormat[_, _]` from `TableOutputFormat`? It seems the problem arises from the differences between generics in Java and in Scala - what can I do for this?

**edit:**

It turns out this is even subtler.  I have tried to define myself a method in the REPL

```
def foo(x: Class[_ <: OutputFormat[_, _]]) = x
```

and I can actually invoke it with

```
foo(classOf[TableOutputFormat[Unit]])
```

or even

```
foo(classOf[TableOutputFormat[_]])
```

for that matters. But I cannot call

```
jobConf.setOutputFormat(classOf[TableOutputFormat[_]])
```

The original signature of `setOutputFormat` in Java is `void setOutputFormat(Class<? extends OutputFormat> theClass)`. How can I call it from Scala?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's very strange, are you 100% sure you have your imports correct (EDIT: yes, this was problem, see comments), and you have the correct versions of artefacts in your build file?  Maybe it could help you if I provide a code snippet from my working project:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapred.TableOutputFormat

val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()

val jobConfig: JobConf = new JobConf(conf, this.getClass)
jobConfig.setOutputFormat(classOf[TableOutputFormat])
jobConfig.set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, outputTable)
```

and some deps I have:

```
"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.3.0-mr1-cdh5.0.0",
"org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "0.96.1.1-cdh5.0.0", 
"org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "0.96.1.1-cdh5.0.0", 

"org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-hadoop-compat" % "0.96.1.1-cdh5.0.0",
"org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-it" % "0.96.1.1-cdh5.0.0", /
"org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-hadoop2-compat" % "0.96.1.1-cdh5.0.0",

"org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-prefix-tree" % "0.96.1.1-cdh5.0.0", 
"org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-protocol" % "0.96.1.1-cdh5.0.0", 
"org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % "0.96.1.1-cdh5.0.0",
"org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-shell" % "0.96.1.1-cdh5.0.0", 

"org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-testing-util" % "0.96.1.1-cdh5.0.0", 
"org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-thrift" % "0.96.1.1-cdh5.0.0",
```

Comment: What version of Scala are you using?

Comment: I do not even understand why `classOf[TableOutputFormat]` compiles for you, as `TableOutputFormat` is generic :-(

Comment: In any case, I am using JVM 1.7, Scala 2.10.3 and "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "0.9.1", "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "0.96.1.1-cdh5.0.0", "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "0.96.1.1-cdh5.0.0", "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % "0.96.1.1-cdh5.0.0"

Comment: Turns out I was importing `import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat` in place of `import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapred.TableOutputFormat` :-/

Comment: Now have could you have missed that  ;)

Comment: @samthebest  You seem to have solved a nut I am trying to crack: hbase 0.96+ with Spark (my version is 1.1.0). Care to take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463183/hbase-0-96-with-spark-v-1-0

Comment: @Andrea I'm afraid, but ```TableOutputFormat``` from ```org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapred``` is deprecated

Answer (score 3):

Since `import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapred.TableOutputFormat` is deprecated, you can use following code as a draft:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat
...
val hConf = HBaseConfiguration.create()

val job = Job.getInstance(hConf)
val jobConf = job.getConfiguration
jobConf.set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, tableName)
job.setOutputFormatClass(classOf[TableOutputFormat[ImmutableBytesWritable]])
...
rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(jobConf)
```