# Spark application throws javax.servlet.FilterRegistration

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, apache-spark

I'm using Scala to create and run a Spark application locally.

My build.sbt:

```
name : "SparkDemo"
version : "1.0"
scalaVersion : "2.10.4"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.0"    exclude("org.apache.hadoop", "hadoop-client")
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.6.0"  excludeAll(
ExclusionRule(organization = "org.eclipse.jetty"))
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-mapreduce-client-core" % "2.6.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "0.98.4-hadoop2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % "0.98.4-hadoop2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "0.98.4-hadoop2"
mainClass in Compile := Some("demo.TruckEvents")
```

During runtime I get the exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>   during calling of... Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class
>   "javax.servlet.FilterRegistration"'s signer information does not match
>   signer information of other classes in the same package

The exception is triggered here:

```
val sc = new SparkContext("local", "HBaseTest")
```

I am using the IntelliJ Scala/SBT plugin.

I've seen that other people have also this problem [suggestion solution](https://ileriseviye.wordpress.com/2014/12/04/how-to-fix-class-javax-servlet-filterregistrations-signer-information-does-not-match-signer-information-of-other-classes-in-the-same-package-when-unit-testing-with-spark-streaming/). But this is a maven build... Is my sbt wrong here? Or any other suggestion how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

See my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463183/hbase-0-96-with-spark-v-1-0/27048490#27048490). The class conflict comes about because HBase depends on `org.mortbay.jetty`, and Spark depends on `org.eclipse.jetty`.  I was able to resolve the issue by excluding `org.mortbay.jetty` dependencies from HBase.

If you're pulling in `hadoop-common`, then you may also need to exclude `javax.servlet` from `hadoop-common`. I have a working HBase/Spark setup with my sbt dependencies set up as follows:

```
val clouderaVersion = "cdh5.2.0"
val hadoopVersion = s"2.5.0-$clouderaVersion"
val hbaseVersion = s"0.98.6-$clouderaVersion"
val sparkVersion = s"1.1.0-$clouderaVersion"

val hadoopCommon = "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % hadoopVersion % "provided" excludeAll ExclusionRule(organization = "javax.servlet")
val hbaseCommon = "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % hbaseVersion % "provided"
val hbaseClient = "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % hbaseVersion % "provided"
val hbaseProtocol = "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-protocol" % hbaseVersion % "provided"
val hbaseHadoop2Compat = "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-hadoop2-compat" % hbaseVersion % "provided"
val hbaseServer = "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % hbaseVersion % "provided" excludeAll ExclusionRule(organization = "org.mortbay.jetty")
val sparkCore = "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided"
val sparkStreaming = "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion % "provided"
val sparkStreamingKafka = "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka" % sparkVersion exclude("org.apache.spark", "spark-streaming_2.10")
```

Comment: Just in case anyone cares, this approach works with maven as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using IntelliJ IDEA， try this:

1. Right click the project root folder, choose *Open Module Settings*
2. In the new window, choose *Modules* in the left navigation column
3. In the column rightmost, select *Dependencies* tab, find *Maven: javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5*
4. Finally, just move this item to the bottom by pressing ALT+Down.

It should solve this problem.

This method came from http://wpcertification.blogspot.ru/2016/01/spark-error-class-javaxservletfilterreg.html

Answer (score 3):

If it is happening in Intellij Idea you should go to the project setting and find the jar in the modules, and remove it. Then run your code with sbt through shell. It will get the jar files itself, and then go back to intellij and re-run the code through intellij. It somehow works for me and fixes the error. I am not sure what was the problem since it doesn't show up anymore.

Oh, I also removed the jar file, and added "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0" through maven by hand and now I can see the error gone.

Answer (score 3):

When you use SBT, FilterRegistration class is present in 3.0 and also if you use JETTY Or Java 8 this JAR 2.5 it automatically adds as dependency,

Fix: Servlet-api-2.5 JAR was the mess there, I resolved this issue by adding servlet-api-3.0 jar in dependencies,

Answer (score 2):

For me works the following:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion.value % "provided",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql"  % sparkVersion.value % "provided",
    ....................................................................
).map(_.excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization = "javax.servlet")))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running inside intellij, please check in project settings if you have two active modules (one for the project and another for sbt).

Probably a problem while importing existing project.

Comment: we should have the two active modules, or only one? do you have more info about this?

Answer (score 0):

try running a simple program without the hadoop and hbase dependency

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.6.0"     excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization = "org.eclipse.jetty"))

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-mapreduce-client-core" % "2.6.0"


libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "0.98.4-hadoop2"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % "0.98.4-hadoop2"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "0.98.4-hadoop2"
```

There should be mismatch of the dependencies. also make sure you have same version of jars while you compile and while you run.

Also is it possible to run the code on spark shell to reproduce ? I will be able to help better.

Comment: Spark standalone works....this is not the issue. I need to have these libraries and I am using sbt - so I expect that runtime/compile is the same