# java.lang.SecurityException:class "javax.servlet.FilterRegistration" information does not match signer information of other classes in same package

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to programming in spark with scala. I am trying to run the following program:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object TestMain {
        def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val logFile = "spark-1.4.1/README.md" // Should be some file on your system

        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
  .setMaster("spark://myhost:7077")
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
        val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
        val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count()
        println("Lines with a: %s, Lines with b: %s".format(numAs, numBs))
    }
}
```

My build.sbt is as follows:

```
name := "TestSpark"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.4.1" % "provided"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.4.0" % "provided"
```

I have tried everything advised on various forums but still am not able to eliminate the error

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "javax.servlet.FilterRegistration"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
```

Any advice? Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spark application throws javax.servlet.FilterRegistration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28086520/spark-application-throws-javax-servlet-filterregistration)